# DropboxServerException - Invalid cursor

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm getting the following back when fetching updates for one our users.

```
DropboxServerException (nginx): 400 Bad Request (Invalid "cursor" 
parameter: this cursor is for a different user.)
```

How can this be remedied? I don't understand how the cursor is tied to a particular user. Can the cursor be refetched/refreshed to be valid?

Comment: A little more info would help. I assume the cursor is for calling `delta`? If so, that's certainly tied to the user the cursor came from, so make sure you know which user you're calling `delta` on behalf of, that you use an access token for that user, and that you pass a cursor that belongs to that user too.

Comment: yes its for the delta. Is there an API to get an appropriate cursor? Also, I was curious on cursors, are you guaranteed that I cursor2 > cursor1 that cursor2 is more current?

Comment: Your first call to `delta` doesn't use a cursor, and subsequent calls should use the cursor that was returned to you. When you say "cursor2 > cursor1", are you talking about alphabetical ordering? No, there's no guarantee. (Treat cursors as opaque strings.)

Comment: So it sounds like if this exception happens start again with no cursor. I was asking about comparing cursors to ensure latest "wins" when committing transaction. I'm guessing I should use another field.

Comment: If this exception happens, it means either you passed an invalid cursor (e.g. one for a different user) or there's a bug on the Dropbox side. If you figure out a way to reproduce it and think it's a Dropbox issue, please open a support ticket: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact. As for comparing cursors, just don't store old ones. :-) When you finish processing a delta, store the new cursor. A simple user-->cursor mapping is all you need.